# React-router producing setState warning

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm using React, Redux and React-Router.  In my MapDispatchToProps() in a React component, I check for a condition and if that condition is true, I call router's browserHistory.push("/newLocation").  For some reason I get this error:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

The funny thing is that my React components are stateless (pure JS functions) so I know I'm not explicitly setting state in a render method.  Diving into the error looks like it is react-router that is trying to set the state:

[image: Stracktrace]

Although even with this warning, the application seems to behave ok.  Not sure how to get rid of this warning though.

Comment: Why do you have that logic in `mapPropsToDispatch` in the first place?

Comment: use the `onEnter` functionality of routes instead

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps` should be a pure function meaning it should change nothing outside the function at all and its only effect should be the return value. You could change certain things with side effects but if the effects trickle down to Redux or to React then you will get errors like is happening here. One harmless side effect is `console.log`. Side effects make for complex applications which is why Redux actively campaigns against them.

Comment: My mapDispatchToProps is still pure-- I don't change state.  Whole point was if there was a particular condition when I first enter that component, I just want to "redirect" to another page, otherwise continue normal processing.  The onEnter attribute for Route worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push functionality is setting state. You should use the `onEnter` functionality built into react-router to test for a condition before entering a route